# CF Blank White Screen No Errors

Tags: coldfusion

I am using CF 10 and I am trying to figure out why I cannot get even an error to tell me whats going wrong.

```
 <cfset result = {} /> 
    <cftry> 

    <!--- Step 1 --->
    <cfset session.exitinterview.name = "test1" >
    <cfset session.exitinterview.todayDate = "test2" >
    <cfset session.exitinterview.title = "test3" >
    <cfset session.exitinterview.department = "test4" >
    <cfset session.exitinterview.hireDate = "test5" >
    <cfset session.exitinterview.terminationDate = "test6" >
    <cfdump var="#session#" label="variables">
    <cfoutput>#session.exitinterview.name#</cfoutput>

    <cfif (isDefined("session.exitinterview.name"))>  
<cfif session.exitinterview.name is not "">
<cfquery datasource="dsn" name="InsertEntry" result="transactionResult">
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[ExitInterview] (Name, JobTitle, DateHired, Dept, InterviewDate, TerminationDate)
 VALUES (
   <cfqueryparam value='#session.exitinterview.name#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
  , <cfqueryparam value='#session.exitinterview.title#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
  , <cfqueryparam value='#session.exitinterview.hireDate#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
  , <cfqueryparam value='#session.exitinterview.department#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
  , <cfqueryparam value='#session.exitinterview.todayDate#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
  , <cfqueryparam value='#session.exitinterview.terminationDate#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
)
</cfquery>
<cfelse>
</cfif>
</cfif>

    <cfcatch type="any"> 
            <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message > 
            <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail > 
        </cfcatch> 
    </cftry>
```

That is the hardcoding thats not working posting to the database, but I am posting through a form like below. The "test1" stuff was just for testing purposes to see why its not posting to the database.

```
<cfset session.exitinterview.name = form.name >
<cfset session.exitinterview.todayDate = form.todayDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.title = form.title >
<cfset session.exitinterview.department = form.department >
<cfset session.exitinterview.hireDate = form.hireDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.terminationDate = form.terminationDate >
```

I am trying to set session variables with a form but even hardcoding like test1, test2 is not working. All I am getting is a blank white screen. Will someone please tell me what I might be missing here?

Comment: `variable [test1] doesn't exist`. fix that, and you'll get `variable [variable] doesn't exist`. something's up with your error handling, seems to be eating your debug output.

Comment: you're dumping `result` somewhere, right?

Comment: @KevinB Sorry im not getting an error its showing me my variables but when I try to insert into the database nothing happens

Comment: Since the code above does not *display* any error messages, how would you even know whether or not an error is occurring? Do not use try/catch just for the heck of it.  It is only useful if you intend to do something with the error or when an error occurs. Otherwise, you are essentially just [swallowing the exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding).  Plus, there is no point adding a try/catch if you have not even verified the code works under normal circumstances.

Comment: oh I thought u were always supposed to test your code with it

Comment: @DavidBrierton - Why? Testing/debugging and error handling are two very different things (and the latter often interferes with the former - case in point - this thread ;-)

Comment: all i know is coding is frustrating lol

Comment: Code does what you tell it to do, not what you *want* it to do ;-) Start small. If something is not working the way you think it should, stop and re-evaluate your assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't see anything because of the `<cftry>` and `<cfcatch>` tags. You'll need to remove or comment them out to see the error.

If the 'test...' variables are not defined that's an error that is caught and will not show on screen.

Comment: hmmm so that worked then putting quotes around it worked but how come something like this would not work? `<cfset session.exitinterview.name = form.name >`

Comment: does it have to be `<cfset session.exitinterview.name = "form.name" >` That just looks wrong to me

Comment: @DavidBrierton are you commenting to me on alex's answer?

Comment: @David what is the error you get? You're setting a variable from session scope to the string "form.name". You probably don't want the double quotes around the form.name.

Comment: im not getting an error can i show u the full thing i am trying to do its just not posting to the database

Comment: its showing my variables ignoring the insert I have

Comment: just posted it I just thought it would be too much code :/

Comment: You have <cfif session.exitinterview.name is not ""> as a condition for insert to run.  I suggest while working on this to remove cftry and cfcatch and that  you dump session.exitinterview.name before the insert. <cfdump var="#session.exitinterview#">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112438/discussion-between-david-brierton-and-alex-baban).